Java Process Linux Command Output Redirection
Following command runs and redirects output to file when I run it on RedHat Linux command line:
mycommand &> mycommand.log
I want to run this command using Java but when I do that it displays command output on STDOUT instead of writing to file:
String command = "mycommand &> mycommand.log";
Process.getRuntime().exec(command);

I cannot use Process.getInputStream() because this command is meant to be executed by another Java process and their Java implementation is hidden from the user, so the redirection must happen within the command and not using Java APIs.

&> is a bashism, and I bet that exec method takes the usual approach of using sh to run the command.

Thanks Shawn. How can I run this command in bash using only one command which will be executed by Java?

Hmm. If I'm reading the docs correctly it doesn't involve a shell at all, so no redirection. ProcessBuilder is the suggested alternative, which lets you specify standard output and error streams. There's an example showing how to send output to a file in the documentation.

Thanks. I will try that, but again I am not sure if target Java implementation (hidden) uses ProcessBuilder under the hood, so not sure if it will work there.

If you mean Runtime.getRuntime().exec  then you are running "mycommand" with arguments "&>" and "mycommand.log". It does not use sh implicitly unless mycommand starts #!/bin/sh.  You will have to run new String[] { "/bin/sh","-c", command} if you want shell redirection.

I imagine you want new ProcessBuilder("mycommand").redirectErrorStream(true).redirectOutput(new File("mycommand.log")).start();.

@VGR I want the command to do the redirect and not use Java API, so: new ProcessBuilder("mycommand &> myfile").start()

When you run the command /usr/bin/echo &> xx in Java, it does not use shell redirects, but passes the arguments &> xx to echo. You can confirm with:
var p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/echo &> xx.log");
p.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
// PRINTS: "&> xx"

In your case, "mycommand" runs with the arguments "&> mycommand.log". Instead, you need to run a shell to have any shell redirect processing, best done using ProcessBuilder:
// test with: String command = "/usr/bin/echo &> xx.log";
var p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", command).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
p.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
// DOES NOT PRINT ANYTHING

The above creates a file: xx.log - containing a blank line in this case with echo.
